# How do I redirect output to a single line in Bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

Let's say we run two programs in the Linux shell, on one line, like this:

```
who -r; date
```

What should I add to obtain one line output?

Comment: ok, I got it. That works like a charm: echo `who -r; date`

Comment: should have been: 
    echo \`who -r; date\`

Comment: You should attempt to ask an actual question in the title of your post since that will get you a lot more attention...

Comment: Ok Max. I will consider this next time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
printf "%s %s\n" "$(who -r)" "$(date)"
```

Lots of quotes, but all are required. More simply:

```
echo $(who -r; date)
```

This one purposefully has no quotes.

---

Another option that does not require all the output from the commands to be captured: groups the commands together and pipe the combined output through `paste`

```bash
{ who -r; date; } | paste -s -d ' '
```

outputs something like

```
         run-level 3  Mar  1 19:44 Tue Apr 18 15:10:19 UTC 2023
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -n `who -r`; echo -n ' '; date
```

Comment: If at all possible, get in the habit of using $( ... ) instead of \`...\`. That way, it's easy to capture the output of a command taht uses captured output. If you use backticks, it's almost impossible.

Comment: @Vatine plus, it's far far easier to read, and it doesn't confuse serverfault's parsing. Better all around.